# python class constants

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

For homework I am re-implementing the socket class in python.  I am not however, well versed in python.  I have a question on syntax.

From the python API when you define a socket you use:

```
import socket
mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM))
```

However, I don't know how to define constants that behave life AF_INET and SOCK_DGRAM.

```
import mySocket
mySocket = mySocket.socket(mySocket.AF_INET,mySocket.SOCK_DGRAM))
```

gives the following errors

```
Undefined variable from import: AF_INET
Undefined variable from import: SOCK_DGRAM
```

The mySocket class currently looks like:

```
class socket:
    AF_INET;
    SOCK_DGRAM;

    def socket(.....
```

Comment: Python does not need semicolons at the end of the line. Seeing them makes me sad. :-(

Comment: I know, it's just habit I guess..

Comment: `socket.AF_INET` is a module constant; `socket.socket.AF_INET` would be a class constant. It gets a bit confusing when the class has the same name as the module that contains it.

Comment: Module-level constants are usually defined at the top-level of the script outside of any functions or classes with statement of the form `NAME = VALUE`. Class-level constants are usually defined inside a `class` block but outside any methods. You could add a `from socket import socket as Socket` to better differentiate between the socket module and the Socket class-level stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the constants at module level, not in your `socket` class:

```
AF_INET = 2
SOCK_DGRAM = 2

class socket:
    def __init__(.....
```

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to nest some constants inside a class which acts as a namespace for them. This makes it possible, for example, to have two unrelated classes in the same module that have a constant with the same name. such as `SIZE`.

Comment: @martineau: of course it is; but the `socket` module uses module-level constants and if you are to emulate that module, then this is what you use. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Those constants are module-level:

**`module1.py`**:

```
CONSTANT1 = 'test'

class YourClass(object):
    class_variable = 12
```

**`module2.py`**:

```
import module1

print module1.CONSTANT1
```